# C++ static array like dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, static

It seems to be remembered that static array in C++ can initialize only from const expression, but if you write:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int n;
  std::cin >> n;
  int a[n];
  std::cout << sizeof(a);

  return 0;
}
```

this program successfully compiles (gcc C++17) and print n * sizeof(int).
But why is this so?

Comment: Why not use `std::vector`?

Comment: Gcc (unfortunately) allows VLAs by default as an extension. Compile with `-std=c++17` and/or `-Wvla -Werror` and it won't.

Comment: But how is VLAs work? Is there any reservation of the stack?

Comment: Use -pedantic to compile.

Comment: Compiler can do the trick. For example, it would allocate memory space in heap, and delete it at every exit point (e.g. all return statements in the function).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Variable-length arrays](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array#Variable-length_arrays) are not part of the standard. They can be present as compiler extensions which is the case with GCC. When compiling you are likely to receive a warning of:

> warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'a' [-Wvla]

When applied to arrays, the [sizeof](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) operator returns the size of the entire array which is the size of the underlying type times the number of elements. The reference states, emphasis mine:

> The size of each VLA instance **does not change** during its lifetime, but
>   on another pass over the same code, it **may** be allocated with a
>   **different size**.

The official GCC documentation titled [6.19 Arrays of Variable Length](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) states:

> These arrays are declared like any other automatic arrays, but with a
>   length that is not a constant expression. The storage is allocated at
>   the point of declaration and deallocated when the block scope
>   containing the declaration exits.

That being said prefer [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) to raw (C style) arrays.